# Setlocale is prompting an error for my Spanish config

Tags: c

I was trying to use setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES"); to get correct Spanish support to my cli app, but constantly I get this errors:

D:\Sami\Code\CuentaBanco\Interfaz\interfaz.c:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
^

D:\Sami\Code\CuentaBanco\Interfaz\interfaz.c:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
^

Below is a portion of my programs source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Interfaz/interfaz.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");

void introducirCreditos(float *creditos, float cargos) {
    int validar;
    do {
        printf("Introduzca los créditos del cliente: ");
        validar = scanf("%f", creditos);
        fflush(stdin); // Limpiar el búfer de entrada

        if (*creditos < 0) {
            printf("Los créditos no pueden ser negativos.\n");
        }
```

I was trying to get á, é , í, ó, ú, ñ characters working properly.

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin);` [invokes *undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) and that therefore it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");` is a *function call*, so it should be inside a function body.

For example:

```c
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
    /* other code */
}
```